# Storyboard and Switch Views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

**I have an iPad app that uses the storyboard board feature and then I have a separate .xib file for another view. I can switch to the separate view and its fine:**

```
-(IBAction)SecondView:(id)sender{

    SecondView *Second = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:Second animated:NO];

}
```

**But when I am in the Second View and try going back I do everything the same just with the first view controller, but It just goes to a black screen:**

```
-(IBAction)FirstView:(id)sender{

    FirstView *First = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:First animated:NO];

}
```

What do you guys think? Am I doing something wrong? What is the best way to switch views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`initWithNibName:bundle` is for loading nib or xib files.

If you are loading from a storyboard, you need to use

```
    FirstView *First= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
```

`IDENTIFIER` is defined in your storyboard, it's in the Utilities, Attributes Inspector on the right side.

**HOWEVER**  your real problem is that you shouldn't be loading from the storyboard at all.  you should just be calling

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

That call will clean up the `presentModalViewController:animated:` that you used to put the modal view controller up in the first place.

Comment: This will create another FirstView while there's already a FirstView in the view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You presented `SecondView` using `presentModalViewController:animated:`, so you need to dismiss it using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

```
- (IBAction)FirstView:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```