# ARC releasing ViewController prematurely

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to ARC and I have been playing with it for less than a week. What I am trying to do is very basic. I have a view controller that displays a button. When I click the button, the corresponding selector needs to be called. However, with ARC, the application crashed with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message. Below is the code from my MainViewController

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    UIButton *testButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80,50,160,50)];
    [testButton setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:testButton];
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked");
}
```

I enabled Zombie Objects and was able to find the following message in the debug logs

```
2012-02-21 22:46:00.911 test[2601:f803] *** -[MainViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6b4bba0
```

Looking at the above message, it seems to me that ARC is prematurely releasing my MainViewController.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without code how the VC is initialized, it's impossible to tell. I guess you just don't have a strong reference to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use the **strong** key

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mvc;
```

Comment: @user1225102: this is most probbably the rigt answer. If not then we need to see some more code.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar symptoms to this, but is using Storyboards and Segues as in my instance - this answer helped me:

[IOS 5 message sent to deallocated instance on alloc command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315815/ios-5-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-on-alloc-command)

The fix was to set the delegate of my MKMapView to nil, during viewWillDisappear. Took ages to find that solution!